# BigQuery array of structs, flatten into one row

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my schema

[image: Here is my schema]

I would like to flatten this into one row, so that all the structs in the prices array turn into columns so that column name would be combined of "market" + " " + "wait", and the columns field value would be "price". Is this possible?

Comment: It would be great to see a sample of the data and what you want to get from that data in the form of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consier below query. You need a dynamic query cause you don't know what value is in **market** and **wait** field in advance and a column name with a space is not allowed in bigquery.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS 
  SELECT 1 id, 'token001' token,
           [STRUCT('market10' AS market, 100 AS wait, 100 AS price),
            STRUCT('market11' AS market, 101 AS wait, 101 AS price)] prices, 100 result
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, 'token002' token,
         [STRUCT('market20' AS market, 200 AS wait, 200 AS price),
          STRUCT('market21' AS market, 201 AS wait, 201 AS price)] prices, 200 result;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, token, result, market || '_' || wait AS col_name, price 
    FROM sample_table, UNNEST(prices)
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(price) FOR col_name IN ('%s'))
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(market || '_' || wait, "','") FROM sample_table, UNNEST(prices)));
```

```
+----+----+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ow | id |  token   | result | market10_100 | market11_101 | market20_200 | market21_201 |
+----+----+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |  1 | token001 |    100 | 100          | 101          | null         | null         |
|  2 |  2 | token002 |    200 | null         | null         | 200          | 201          |
+----+----+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```